# Open a file with keyboard that is actual a dir

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I hate using mouse in IDEA editors, and what bugs me is that I can't find a way to open file that has been translated with Babel for example to ES5. The file has 2 sub files that are translated to ES5. So when I press Alt+1 I jump to Project view, find the file, press enter and instead opening file content in the editor it opens a folder tree.

[image]

How can I open file with the keyboard instead opening file directory?

Comment: `F4` will work as well (depends on a Keymap I guess; I'm using Default one).

Comment: Make this an answere so that I can vote for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use <kbd>F4</kbd> -- it's a standard shortcut (in Default keymap) to open file for editing.

In case if you need to assign another shortcut .. or find out what shortut it is in your keymap/OS:

- `Settings/Preferences | Keymap`
- Look for `Main Menu | View | Jump to Source` action